# Problems with " invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char' [-fpermissive]"

Tags: c++

I just started learning c++ and I'm having an issue with "invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char' [-fpermissive]" in my source code.

```
    const string alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    string gameAlphabet = alphabet;

    char letterguess;
    int limbnumber = 0;

    do
    {
        cout << "Please choose a letter: ";
        cin >> letterguess;
        cout << letterguess;

        if (theWord.find(letterguess) == string::npos)
        {
            int temp2 = theWord.find(letterguess);
            theWord[temp2] = letterguess;
            int temp3 = gameAlphabet.find(letterguess);
            if (gameAlphabet[temp3] = " ")
            {
                cout << "You have already guessed this letter, please try again.";
            }
            gameAlphabet[temp3] = " ";
            cout << gameAlphabet;
        }
        else
        {
            limbnumber++;
            int temp1 = gameAlphabet.find(letterguess);
            gameAlphabet[temp1] = " ";

            if (limbnumber == 7 )
            {
                cout << "\n\nSorry " << playername << ", you lose.";
                cout << "Please try again.";
            }

        }
```

The "invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char' [-fpermissive]" occurs in lines 19, 23 and 30.  If you guys can see any mistakes I've made, let me know. Thanks!

Comment: `gameAlphabet[temp3]` needs a character. You can't fit multiple characters into one.

Comment: `if (gameAlphabet[temp3] = " ")` probably doesn't do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

The error occurs in statements like this

```
gameAlphabet[temp3] = " ";
```

`" "` is a string literal that in expressions is converted to pointer to the first character of the literal. Instead of a string literal you have to use an object of type char. For example

```
gameAlphabet[temp3] = ' ';
```

That is instead of double quotes you need to use single quotes. Though you could write using the string literal the following way

```
gameAlphabet[temp3] = " "[0];
```

But this code only confuses users.

Also take into account that your program is invalid. For example let consider this code snippet

```
    if (theWord.find(letterguess) == string::npos)
    {
        int temp2 = theWord.find(letterguess);
        theWord[temp2] = letterguess;
```

Condition `theWord.find(letterguess) == string::npos` meabs that the character was not found, So the next statement

```
        int temp2 = theWord.find(letterguess);
```

returns `string::npos` You may not use this value as an index in the string

```
        theWord[temp2] = letterguess;
```

Also after this statement

```
        int temp3 = gameAlphabet.find(letterguess);
```

you have to check whether temp3 is equal to string::npos. Otherwise the code has undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (gameAlphabet[temp3] = " ")
...
gameAlphabet[temp3] = " ";
...
gameAlphabet[temp1] = " ";
```

In each of these cases, you're assigning a pointer (because `" "` is actually a `const char*`) to a character within your string `gameAlphabet`.

To remedy this, change `" "` to `' '` which is a single space character.

Also, I'm guessing the `if` statement was probably supposed to be comparison, which means it should use the comparison operator `==`.

Comment: `""` is a `const char[1]`.

Comment: Obviously you are right. I was just trying to make a point, burrowing the same terminology used by the compiler error.